# Пояснение цикла while

Tags: c, циклы

Если стоит инкремент после printf, как переменная i видит что к ней добавили +1. Если их местами поменять с начало ++i потом printf тогда понятно, а если на оборот не понятно как видна переменная.

```
main(){
   int i=0;
   while(i<10){
       printf("%d\n",i);
       ++i;
   }
}
```

Comment: В одном случае выведет от 0 до 9.
В другом от 1 до 10. Экспериментируйте!

Comment: какой результат будет мне понятно. Вопрос задал другой.

Comment: @avdoshkin в принципе можно написать и посмешнее. Сравните два варианта:

       while(i<10) printf("%d\n",i++);

       while(i<10) printf("%d\n",++i);

Comment: ++i до того, как его значение будет использовано, а i++ — после того

Comment: Но вопрос другой был)

Comment: Если мы выводим printf("%d\n", i); ++i, как i понимает что к ней добавили +1. Если инкремент стоит после printf.

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Совсем непонятно, что же Вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Она не видит. В первом случае на первой итерации, будет выведено "0", во втором "1". При первом выводе, будет выведено то значение, которое было присвоено при инициализации переменной, так как ранее больше не было операций над ней. Вы что-то путаете, перепроверьте снова.

Answer (score 1):

как работает пост-инкремент (переменная++)

1. использовать значение
2. затем приростить значение

как работает пре-инкремент (++переменная)

1. приростить значение
2. использовать значение

пре и пост инкремент свои свойства проявляет **только** на границе блоков текущего контекста. Например:

```
    постинкремент

for (int i = 0;; i++) // значение переменной i равно 0
{
                      // внутри блока переменная все еще i равна 0
}                     // теперь к переменной i **прибавляется** единица и цикл выполняется еще раз

    преинкремент

for (int i = 0;; ++i) // к переменной i **прибавляется** единица
{
                      // внутри блока переменная i равна 1
}                     // цикл повторяется еще раз
```

Comment: @perfect

       инкремент работает только на границе блоков.

Это как так? 

    for (int i = 0;; i++) // значение переменной i равно 0
    {
                      // внутри блока переменная все еще i равна 0
       printf("%d\n", i++);
       printf("%d\n", i++);
    }          

На какой границе происходит приращение i?

Comment: здесь блок начинается на for вот это и есть грань начала контекста (я немного поравил ответ), а на закрывающей скобке блок кончается.

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. Нельзя ли по человечески объяснить? Есть пример, когда приращение происходит перед вызовом printf, и какие там блоки?

Comment: ну можно попробовать объяснить так, есть такое понятие как область видимости, надеюсь это понятно - вот это я и называю блоком то что к этой области присоединено это грань области видимости. alexz ты пишешь: Есть пример, когда приращение происходит перед вызовом printf - как может произойти прирощение если мы еще не в этой области видимости?

Comment: @perfect, и все же блоки

    for (int i = 9; i < 5; i++)
      cout << i << '\n';

и

    for (int i = 9; i < 5; ++i)
      cout << i << '\n';

дадут одинаковый результат, независимо от пре/пост инкремента и Ваших рассуждений 

        // внутри блока переменная все еще i равна 0
      ....
        // внутри блока переменная i равна 1

о величине пре/пост инкрементируемой переменной внутри блока

Comment: @perfect В Си области видимости -- единица трансляции, процедура, блок. Ни ++i, ни i++ области видимостей не создают. Тем более, что в данном случае i локализована в for (C++).

Comment: @avp согласен с вами проверил для for не работает, а вот для while работает (проверял в линуксе, надо в widows проверить). @alexlz про то что инкремент создает область видимости я не писал

Comment: подскажите как код в коментарий вставлять?

Comment: 4 пробела перед каждой строчкой кода.

--

А вообще, Вы прямо какую-то магию связываете с ++i и i++.

На самом деле все проще. Операции ++i и i++  вырабатывают *значение* и *побочный эффект*. 

**Значение** участвует в другой опрерации (например, операции присваивания или передается в функцию и т.п.), а если такой операции нет, как в случае с циклом `for(...; ...; i++)`, то бесследно исчезает.

**Побочный эффект** заключается в изменении самой переменной (в памяти).

Так вот, *значением* i++ будет величина i до ее увеличения, а ++i - после. *Сразу* после этого значение i уже другое.